# Parking Calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I am working on a parking calculator in JS I will include the directions that are giving me issues:

"The parking rate is $1 per hour, up to 4 hours day of entry. $6/day thereafter. 24 hours makes a day."

My issue is that I can get it to calculate after 24 hours but I can't get it to calculate just for every 24 hours. Like if you were to enter 25-47 it should still cost $6 but at 48 hours it should cost $12 and so forth. Thanks for any help.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function parkingFee() {           
    var parkingHours = parseFloat(prompt("Enter hours parked:"));

    if (parkingHours <= 4.0 && parkingHours > 0.5) {
      var fee = parkingHours * 1.0;
      document.write("Parking fee is $" + fee);
    }
    else if (parkingHours <= 0.5) {
      document.write("There are no parking fees.");
    }
    else if (parkingHours > 4.0 && parkingHours <= 24.0) {
      var fee2 = 6.0;
      document.write("Parking fee is $" + fee2);
    }
    else if (parkingHours > 24) {           
      var fee3 = parkingHours * 6.0 / 24;
      document.write("Parking fee is $" + fee3);
    }                       
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the maths on the `parkingHours > 24` from 
`parkingHours * 6.0 / 24` to `parseInt(parkingHours / 24) * 6`

when i was playing about with your code i got the result your after with that :)

Comment: Thank you! I kick myself sometimes when the answer is so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Your function modified. Use `Math.floor` to determine number of days over 1.

```js
function parkingFee()
{

  var parkingHours = parseFloat(prompt("Enter hours parked:"));

  if (parkingHours <= 4.0 && parkingHours > 0.5) {
    var fee = parkingHours * 1.0;
    document.write("Parking fee is $" + fee);
  }
  else if (parkingHours <= 0.5) {
    document.write("There are no parking fees.");
  }
  else {
    var fee2 = 6.0;
    document.write("parking fee is $" + ((Math.floor(parkingHours / 24) || 1) * fee2));
  }       
}

parkingFee();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!